# DragDrop on NetworkGraph?

Tags: highcharts

Good evening!

I'm trying to get coordinates of a dropped point on a network graph.

Unfortunately, something seems to goes wrong using the informations from the doc, but I may also have missed a crucial point.

My options looks like this one:

```
{ 
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dragDrop: {
            draggableX: true,
            draggableY: true,
          },
          point: {
            events: {
              drop: function (e) {
                 console.log('I have been dropped', this, e);
              },
              click: function (e) {
                console.log('I have been clicked', this, e);
              }
            }
          }
        }
    },
}
```

A reproduction case can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/41wvq62t/2/

Any idea of what's going wrong?

Comment: I think this is the bug. I reported the issue on the github page and you can track it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `series.dragDrop` option is not supported for NetworkGraph, and consequently, point drag/drop events are unavailable. This inconsistency in the documentation has already been reported and will be corrected soon.

As a workaround, you can wrap the onMouseUp and onMouseDown functions from the networkGraph module to detect drag/drop position.

**Example code:**

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype, 'onMouseUp', function(proceed, point) {
    console.log('Drop ', point.name + ': ', point.plotX);
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });
}(Highcharts));

(function(H) {
  H.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype, 'onMouseDown', function(proceed, point) {
    console.log('Drag ', point.name + ': ', point.plotX);
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/htj0g619/

**API Reference:**
:https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: are you able to explain this behavior ? https://jsfiddle.net/sa6trfuo/9/

Nodes are moving each time they're refreshed..

On my local env, I can even see something stranger than that: https://www.loom.com/share/06510e565d3a4342b589d79bd7a0bbeb

Comment: is this what you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/or3hxs96/?

Comment: Nop. If you try to move a single node, it will be erased during refresh. Nonetheless, I've found something I'll share by the end of the week.
Briefly, what I have to do is to reconcile known positions and the ones from updated dataset.